# Psychological effects of HLD Syndrome on human males?

Tags: magic, humans, modern-age

The next year 50 % of the male population unlocks the *inner-eye* by a blessing of the young god Migitow. The *inner-eye* is the gift of being the master of your own dreams.

Much more common in unattractive males the dream-world is like a videogame with endless options. Only your imagination and personality are your limits. Your memory works like a ¨save game¨ so you can re-log the dream of yesterday if you want it and remember the dream or someone/ something of said dream. You can join other dreams and people can join your dreams if you have a gold ring or necklace. The dream world is like games on the internet in this regard. But you can't kill someone or be killed in ¨multiplayer dreams¨.

Hyper lucid dreams, aka H.L.D Syndrome, are so powerful that if you somehow die while dreaming you have a chance to die in the real world. This is an example of how powerful the dreams are.

Now here is my question:

**What would be the outcome of living in a dual reality: One where your dreams are hard or impossible and the other when it happens all the time?**

For example : Jack is an ugly teen living in a low class family. He suffers every time he sees a beautiful girl and couples. Suddenly he can control his dreams and in no time he creates a reality where he can experience love with any girl of the middle ages and later show her the universe in his starship. But then he awakes. This is an example but other material things  or wishes apply when dreaming isn't?

Notes : In  Hyper lucid dreams 1 second is equal to 3 real minutes. To enter this state of sleeping absolute silence and serenity are needed. You can awake and thereby end the lucid dream if you really want it, otherwise it wont end. Writing before sleeping grants the dreams more logic.

Comment: I think, much like in the film *Inception*, you would end up with a lot of people who choose to spend their life in the dream world, "*The dream has become their reality*" to quote the film. The more believable people's dreams become, the worse this is going to get.

Comment: This could be a tricky one to answer.  On one hand, it could lead to the starvation of millions of people who choose not to leave their dreams to eat.  It could enslave the world.  Or, one might point out that this is the same driving force that inspires people to do great things with their lives.  Refined properly, it's the stuff that martial arts legends are made of.  The gamut for answers is really really wide.

Comment: You can die but can't be killed? So jumping off a cliff is suicidal, but if I ask my friend to push me, I'm perfectly safe and will land unharmed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### We already see effects of something similar to this

It is, perhaps, a controversial topic but when reading this what first sprang to mind was pornography. There are cases where people become addicted to the ease at which they can achieve their goals of seeing attractive people naked, performing acts they have a particular fetish for or interacting with them directly through paid-for services.

This addiction can effect the consumer's ability to function in the real world, their ability to talk to the opposite sex - raises their expectations of what will be done and how willing people will be to follow their desires. It leads to an expectation that means they overlook their own selfishness.

This effect, I believe, will carry through all aspects of life. Men will imagine themselves the best lovers, fighters, scientists and when it comes to these situations in the real world they will fall far short of their expectations and, because of this, feel even less keen on reality.

In short I believe it will lead to mass addiction that society will need to face - offering specialised counsellors to deal with this eppidemic. It will probably also lead to a rise in female specialists in all sectors. Perhaps even leading to men being given less responsibility given their potential lack of ability to gauge their own abilities.

Answer (score 1):

Like being in the perfect VR videogame.  You never want to come out.  Think Gamer or WALL-E.  You spend all your time sleeping, and when you're not sleeping, life kinda sucks alot more so you take sleeping pills just because you are addicted to dreaming.  Sleeping all the time is unhealthy.  The ultimate would be to put yourself in a medically induced light coma, and be taken care of in some medical care facility which profits immensely off of just putting sleep-addicted people into that perpetual-dreaming state, and maintaining their health as best they can.

It becomes a dystopian reality.  I agree that males would be more affected than females, because of our masculinity, and our urge to control or dominate things.  Purely hormone driven, but productive males would become scarce, driving the demand for high-functioning females to take over the business and demands of real life.  As a result, the world would become a more peaceful place.  Technology advancement would slow, but sustainability would go up.  Lesbian relationships with surrogate seeds would be much more common. Also asexual w/ surrogate seed, but less common because a well-supported family still needs a breadwinner and a caregiver.

Once females were dominant in society, they would try to cut off access to the dream state, and for good reason.  They still love their children, some of whom are males, and they want to see them flourish in real life.  That's part of their hormonal motherly instincts.  Just as a mother doesn't want her son to become an IV drug addict, so she doesn't want him to fall victim to the addiction of dreaming.

Males would become more feminine, and evolution would run its course, so that the guys who are addicted to dreaming just sort of die off quickly, and without reproducing.

Perhaps the state of society would gradually shift towards a one-world order, or a more socialistic world platform.

That's assuming all males are able to dream in this way.  If it's only wealthy males, or males in the USA, who have access to the materials needed to dream in this way, then it would totally go down very differently than this!